# whats the difference between the two codes below, (i ran them, but they gave different outputs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I was working on a challenge in JavaScript and the instruction is to divide the number of volunteers with the that of neighbourhoods.

I used the `.length` array method to get the length and performed the operation, but one thing that bugs me is that I tried it with two approaches, one passed and one couldn't pass the test, the codes are below

This one passed the test

```
const function(volunteers, neighborhood){
  let neighborhoodLent = neighborhood;
  let volunteersLength = volunteers.length
  let evaluate =  neighborhoodLent / volunteersLength;

  return evaluate;
}
```

This one below failed the test.

```
const function(volunteers, neighborhood){
  return volunteers.length / neighborhood.length
}
```

When given an array like the one below

```
const volunteers = [
  'Sally',
  'Jake',
  'Brian',
  'Hamid'
];

const neighbourhoods = [
  'Central Valley',
  'Big Mountain',
  'Little Bridge',
  'Bricktown',
  'Brownsville',
  "Paul's Boutique",
  'Clay Park',
  'Fox Nest'
];
```

the output should be 2.

My concern is now to know the difference between the two approaches I used and why the other passed and the other failed.
please I will appreciate your help in clarifying me

Comment: One potential issue is that `const function(volunteers, neighborhood){` will throw a `SyntaxError`, so it won't pass a test if the test requires valid code

Comment: how? this ```const function( volunteers, neighborhoods){}``` is the starter function template they gave me

Comment: `const function() {}` is not valid syntax. `function` is a reserved keyword. `const` is assigning a value to a name, so you could provide a name like `const divide = function () {}`. Or, you could just not use `const` and use a named function like `divide() {}`

Comment: Why does the first function divide the number of neighbourhoods with volunteers and the other function does the opposite?

Comment: Your first function should not work. You don't even grab the length of the neighbourhood array

Comment: Even if you corrected the `const` issue in the first function, it would always return `NaN`, since you're dividing an Array by a Number

Answer (score 1):

How your first code passed. Dividing array by number is NaN. Try this.

```
function calculate(volunteers, neighborhoods) {
    return volunteers.length / neighborhoods.length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've used incorrect syntax to declare function. Pay attention that `function` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. So `const function {...}` is not valid syntax. You should name your function after `function` keyword. Try to write like this:

```js
const volunteers = [
    'Sally',
    'Jake',
    'Brian',
    'Hamid'
];

const neighbourhoods = [
    'Central Valley',
    'Big Mountain',
    'Little Bridge',
    'Bricktown',
    'Brownsville',
    "Paul's Boutique",
    'Clay Park',
    'Fox Nest'
];

function calc (volunteers, neighborhood) {
    return neighborhood.length / volunteers.length;
}

const constCalc = (volunteers, neighborhood) =>{
    return neighborhood.length / volunteers.length;
}

console.log(`usual declaration`, calc(volunteers, neighbourhoods));
console.log(`arrow function:`, constCalc(volunteers, neighbourhoods));
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The result should be the same

- In method `two` instead of `volunteers.length / neighbourhoods.length` it should be `neighbourhoods.length / volunteers.length` because in mathematical operations such as division, the order of the factors alters the result

Fixed code:

```js
const volunteers = ['Sally','Jake','Brian','Hamid']
const neighbourhoods = ['Central Valley','Big Mountain','Little Bridge','Bricktown','Brownsville',"Paul's Boutique",'Clay Park','Fox Nest']

const one = (volunteers, neighbourhoods) => {
  const neighbourhoodsLength = neighbourhoods.length
  const volunteersLength = volunteers.length
  const evaluate = neighbourhoodsLength / volunteersLength

  return evaluate
}

const two = (volunteers, neighbourhoods) => {
  return neighbourhoods.length / volunteers.length
}

console.log('one:', one(volunteers, neighbourhoods))
console.log('two:', two(volunteers, neighbourhoods))
```